# Is there a Math3d function to multiply a vertex array with a 4x4 matrix?

Tags: c++

I've looked at the source code and I haven't found anything, but I want to be shure, just in case. Is there any math3d function that takes a vertex array and multiplies it by a m3dmatrix44f?

Comment: What source code?  And when you say a vertex array, do want to iterate over the vertices and transform them by the matrix?

Comment: the math3d source code. It's a library for manipulating matrixes, vectors and things like that, and I think it's part of the GLTools library. And when I say vertex array I mean exactly that, iterating over every vertex and transforming them by the matrix

Comment: You mean math3d.h/.cpp as found within the OpenGL Super Bible sources?

Comment: Yeah. Well, I have read it online, but I think it is the same as the one within the Super Bible sources

Comment: @XaitormanX: This has nothing to do with OpenGL. The Superbible's math libraries are *not* OpenGL.

Comment: I know, but I couldn't find any better tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend switching to [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) or [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) for matrix-wrangling.  Eigen has SIMD routines to speed up batch operations.

They're both header-only.